# Bootstrap zoom in prevent Image shrink as well top on the top of image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have banner image in Bootstrap row, inside container. but I don't want to shrink the image with rest of the elements when user zooms out. 
My code looks something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Bootstrap 4 Responsive Layout Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-3">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand mr-3">Tutorial Republic</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Services</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">About</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Register</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</nav>



      <div class="container d-flex h-100">
      <div class="row " style="position:relative;" >
 <img src="https://cdn.slidemodel.com/wp-content/uploads/20306-01-electron-powerpoint-template-16x9-1-558x314.jpg" style="width:100%;height:500px;"/>      
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  intro-info2 " style="margin-top:70px"></div>
          <div style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;color:white">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
            <h2>HTML</h2>
            <p>HTML is the standard markup language for describing the structure of the web pages. Our HTML tutorials will help you to understand the basics of latest HTML5 language, so that you can create your own website.</p>
            <p><a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
            <h2>CSS</h2>
            <p>CSS is used for describing the presentation of web pages. CSS can save a lot of time and effort. Our CSS tutorials will help you to learn the essentials of latest CSS3, so that you can control the style and layout of your website.</p>
            <p><a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success">Learn More &raquo;</a></p>

    </div>
    <hr>

</body>
</html>
```

I cannot take the image out of the container. and I need the image to go with scroll, so I cannot make it as position fixed. Please help me.

Expected Output:
[image: This is expected output] I want this background image inside the container on the top.

Comment: i want the image should full screen width in case of zoom out and given a fixed height as well. problem is when I scroll the page it should move along with scroll

Comment: updated the question with expected output. I want that image to be  full screen width in case of zoom out. This  image is inside a row div & at the top of the page

Comment: On a 1920x1200px display (mine) your `container { max-width: 1140px }`, which means your image image should be 1140/19.2 = 59.375% of the total browser width (when full screen). Using `59.375%` will not work as the image will zoom in/out too. BUT, using `59.375vw` will do the trick as the image is now relative to the browser viewport instead of its parent width. Remove the `height: 500px` and make width `width: 59.375vw`. Try zooming in/out. I'm have not test this on a mobile, though.

Comment: Is this right: you want the image to be of height 500px (and retain its proper ratio) no matter the zoom status of the browser? And fill the width of the container too (this means you cannot have a fixed height)? Either fill the container (with proper ratio the height will change) OR have a fixed height (with proper ratio and not fill the container).